# lazy=True in (Flask-)SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm learning SQLAlchemy and I want to make sure that I've understood the `backref` parameter in `relationship` correctly.

For example

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)

    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Say I have a User object `j = models.User.query.get(1)`. My question is, is there any difference between the following things?

- `j.posts`
- `Post.query.filter_by(author=j).all()`
- `Post.query.with_parent(j).all()`
- `Post.query.with_parent(j, property='posts').all()`
- `Post.query.with_parent(j, property=User.posts).all()`

The results returned are same, but I don't know whether the SQL statements executed are identical.

#### What I've tried

The [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_parent) says:

> `with_parent(instance, property=None, from_entity=None)`
>
> ...the given `property` can be `None`, in which case a search is performed against this Query object’s target mapper.

So the last three statements seem same, but I don't really understand what does *this Query object’s target mapper* refer to. Is it `Post` in this case, for this query is performed on `Post`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if the generated SQL statements are identical, the commands you enlisted may have a different impact on your application, e.g. `j.posts` will cache (*memoize*, do not confuse with Werkzeug caching) results you have got, while others will fetch them every single time.

If you remove `.all()` from your queries you can simply print them:

```
query = Post.query.filter_by(author=j)
print(query)
```

Which would result in:

```
SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.body AS post_body, post.user_id AS post_user_id 
FROM post 
WHERE ? = post.user_id
```

Using `.all()` is essentially like getting `[m for m in query]`).

The trick with query-printing will not work for `j.posts` which will return something like:

```
> print(j.posts)
> [Post(...), Post(..)]
```

Still, you can see all the silently emitted queries using built-in sqlalchemy loggers. See the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event
import logging


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/tests.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)

    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
user = User(username='test', posts=[Post(body='some body')])
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()

# start logging
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
j = User.query.get(1)

queries = {
    "j.posts",
    "Post.query.filter_by(author=j)",
    "Post.query.with_parent(j)",
    "Post.query.with_parent(j, property='posts')",
    "Post.query.with_parent(j, property=User.posts)",
}

def test_queries():
    for name in queries:
        print('\n=======')
        print('Executing %s:' % name)
        query = eval(name)
        print(query)

test_queries()  # you should see j.posts query here
print('Second test')
test_queries()  # but not here
```

Getting back to your question: yes, the emitted SQL queries are identical.

In *Query object’s target mapper*, *Query object's target* refers to `Post` in your example. Decoupling this, when you declare `Post` class, inheriting from  `db.Model`, for SQLAlchemy it is like creating an *object* Post and *mapping* the properties of this object to columns of specially created table.

Underneath there is an instance of `Mapper` class, which is responsible for the mapping for every single model that you create (learn more about mapping here: [Types of Mappings](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping)). You can simply get this mapper calling `class_mapper` on your model or `object_mapper` on an instance of your model:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import object_mapper, class_mapper, 
from sqlalchemy.orm.mapper import Mapper
assert object_mapper(j) is class_mapper(User)
assert type(class_mapper(User)) is Mapper
```

The Mapper has all the necessary information about the columns and relations you have in your model. When calling `Post.query.with_parent(j)` this information is used to find a property (i.e. relationship) relating Post and User objects, so in your case to populate 'property' with `User.posts`.

Comment: This answer is awesome, but still my humble mind has a few questions: [*If you care to answer them I will give you a (large) bounty!*] **1.** shouldn't _query object’s target mapper_ be a `Mapper`? Why is `Post`, an object, the "target mapper", instead of something like `class_mapper(Post)`? **2.** You said "`j.posts` will cache results you have got", so what if the database is updated after I call `j.posts` for the first time? Won't this cause inconsistency? **3.** What exactly does "caching" mean? Extracting data from the database and store it in Python objects?

Comment: **4.** According to [the docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.2/models/#one-to-many-relationships), lazy loading means _load the data as necessary_, but how much is necessary? Take `j.posts` for example, what is being cached, for `lazy=True`, `lazy=False` and `lazy=subquery`respectively? [*Yeah I know I have many many questions, so I will give you a big bounty, maybe 150, if you can answer them!*]

Comment: 1. You are right that's what I wanted to write 2, 3 and 4: Will "cache" them until any session changing operation is performed (e.g. `db.session.commit()` or `db.session.rollback()`). It does exactly as you guessed extracts the data and stores them in Python objects (those are instrumented objects to be precise); 4. If you use eager loading, your relationship will be populated with first call e.g. with `j = User.query.get(1)`, not when you access `j.posts` for the first time.

Comment: Question 1, 2 and 3 have been solved! _4. If you use eager loading, your relationship will be populated with first call e.g. with `j = User.query.get(1)`, not when you access `j.posts` for the first time._ But when I changed the `lazy=True` in the code in your answer to `lazy=False` and run it, I can still see some SQL statements when `test_queries()` is first executed...

Comment: It works as expected if you use `j = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id==1).one()`. Seemingly using `.get()` prevents eager loading, contrary to what I thought.

Comment: This is quite counter-intuitive, and IMO worth opening another question for :/ Anyway, thanks for teaching me many thing today! But unfortunately this question is _currently_ too new for me to start a bounty on. I will start one and give it to you after the system permits me to do so, [which would take at least 2+1 days](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). PS: [Printing messages with color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python) can make the debug output much clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I agree the strange get() behavior is a separate question. Personally I almost always use full queries rather than get() as those are more potent. PS: The get() behavior may be not intended and related to this bug: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/1763/eager-loader-options-parameters-for

Comment: It's really nice to see it's probably a bug. Also, why is full queries more potent than `get()`s? I thought `get()` is essentially a shortcut of the corresponding full query!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149392/discussion-between-krassowski-and-sun-qingyao).

Answer (score 1):

To see the queries you can run your python script with `-i` and then run each query individually and it will print out the SQL code it runs.
Example:

`main.py`:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import os

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    password = Column(String(12))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< User(name={}, fullname={}, password={} )>".format(self.name, self.fullname, self.password)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

ed_user= User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', password='edpassword')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
session = Session()
session.add(ed_user)
session.add_all([
    User(name='wendy', fullname='Wendy Williams', password='foobar'),
    User(name='mary', fullname='Mary Contraty', password='xxg527'),
    User(name='fred', fullname='Fred Flinstone', password='blah')
])
session.commit()
os.system('clear')
```

Now you run it with `python -i main.py`, type: `session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first()` and you will see the SQL generated. After [running](https://pastebin.com/8iExFNyT) all of your tests I concluded that they are all **identical**.  With this method you can test any query and see if there is any difference.

p.s. I added the `os.system('clear')` to remove all the unnecessary output from creating the database and some other stuff.

Comment: I'm using FLASK-SQLAlchemy so I'm not quite familiar with SQLAlchemy. Can you make the code a complete, runnable one? For example, adding the import statements.

Comment: @SunQingyao Edited, sorry for forgetting the imports :)

Comment: Experiment done, result: **all of these 5 queries are identical.** You may want to include the result in your answer, so that I can accept it :) [Here is the code](https://pastebin.com/8iExFNyT), for future reference.

Comment: @SunQingyao Done. If you have anything to add you can freely edit the answer. :)